# how to find repeated sub sequences of numbers in big string of numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, sequence

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

the problem is:

**Assumption 1:** we have undefined number of sub strings(s1,s2,s3,…) that each of this sub strings are a sequence of 100 numbers (Integer number between 20000000 and 80000000) that they have been chosen randomly.
We don’t have any knowledge about the numbers that make this sub strings and the number of sub strings.
the important thing here is the order of numbers in sub string not the relation between them.`

**Assumption 2:** we have a big and long string include millions of numbers, this long string is made of repetition of sub string that mentioned in assumption 1. The name of this string is “S”.

We simplify the example like below:
Each sub string contain four number instead of 100 number and each number is between 20 and 80 instead of 20000000 and 80000000:
We have the “S” string, our algorithm must find sub string s1 and s2 and s3 from string “S”.

```
S= 71,59,32,51,45,22,53,25,66,72,71,26,32,28,45,72,59,51,53,66,59,51,53,66,59,51,53,66,22,59,51,25,72,32,26,53,28,66,45,72,71,32,45,72,71,32,45,72, ... .
```

The output of this algorithm is like below:

```
S1= 59,51,53,66
S2= 22,25,26,28
S3= 71,32,45,72
```

NOTE:if we are lucky the sub strings can coming in string "s " without combining and repeated one after another.

I want the algorithm that find the number of sub string(s1,s2,s3s, …)
And also find the sub string(s1,s2,s3, …) that make the string “S”.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's nothing here about design patterns, so that leaves us with java, python and oracle. Which is this about?

Comment: _I want the algorithm that find_ ... of course you want this but have you tried something already?

Comment: Fix your problem description to add enough constraints, since (as far as I can understand from your current description) the following trivial solution solves the problem as currently stated: Take the first 4 numbers and put them into S1; take the next 4 numbers and put them into S2; etc.

Comment: `number of substrings (s1,s2,s3)` -> `return 3`

Comment: "we have undefined number": what do you mean by `undefined`?

Comment: Is it possible a same number is shared by S1, S2, S3?

Comment: How about we make `S1 = S[1..100], S2 = S[101..200], ..., Sn = [100n - 99, 100n], ...` to get a trivial solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work::

```
import java.util.*;

public class ComputeSubSequence {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String rootString = "59,22,51,25,53,66,26,28,59,51,22,53,25,66,71,26,32,28,45,59,72,51,71,53,66,32,45,72,22,25,26,59,51,28,71,53,32,66,45,72";
  Integer sizeOfSubString = 4;
  List < String > rootList = new ArrayList < String > (Arrays.asList(rootString.split("\\s*,\\s*")));

  Set < String > setValue = new LinkedHashSet < String > ();
  Set < Integer > setValueNew = new LinkedHashSet < Integer > ();
  HashMap < Integer, String > map = new LinkedHashMap < Integer, String > ();

  for (String string: rootList) {
   map.put(Integer.valueOf(string), Integer.valueOf(Collections.frequency(rootList, string)).toString());
   setValue.add(Integer.valueOf(Collections.frequency(rootList, string)).toString());
  }

  for (String string: setValue) {
   for (Map.Entry < Integer, String > entry: map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().contains(string)) {
     setValueNew.add(entry.getKey());
    }
   }
  }

  List < Integer > listOfNames = new ArrayList < Integer > (setValueNew);

  Integer j = 0;
  Integer i = 0;
  Integer count = 1;
  for (i = sizeOfSubString; i <= listOfNames.size(); i = i + sizeOfSubString) {
   System.out.println("S" + count + "=" + listOfNames.subList(j, i).toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
   count++;
   j = j + sizeOfSubString;

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: hi . thanks for your answer but your output is not the same as the output that I expected. the output must be S1= 59,51,53,66
S2= 22,25,26,28
S3= 71,32,45,72   and your output are 
SubString1=[66, 59, 45, 22]
SubString2=[32, 25, 26, 28]
SubString3=[51, 53, 71, 72]
.

Comment: note : if we are lucky the sub strings can coming in string "s " without combining.  S=71,59,32,51,45,22,53,25,66,72,71,26,32,28,45,72,59,51,53,66,59,51,53,66,59,51,53,66,22,59,51,25,72,32,26,53,28,66,45,72,71,32,45,72,71,32,45,72 ... .    as you see in the new example  s1 and s3 do not combined and repeated one after another.

Comment: I want to confirn:  Your expexted output is:                           
S1= 59,51,53,66
S2= 22,25,26,28
S3= 71,32,45,72  



Is it ok if i change my program which will give output as:    
S1=66,59,45,22  
S2=32,25,26,28  
S3=5,53,71,72    

Or you want all substring exactly same as your expected substring. Because i think logic behind this is like:

A. All substring must be of length 4     
B. Any number must not repeat in another substring.

If this is only logic then my program is fit in this logic . We just need to change the displayed output.

Please confirm. Thanks :)

Comment: THE OUTPUT MUST BE JUST LIKE THIS:  S1= 59,51,53,66     S2= 22,25,26,28     S3= 71,32,45,72    .  THANKS FOR YOUR ATTENTION.

Comment: VishalZ :Thanks for your help.
But I think some where I could not say my exact meaning of the problem.
so could you please give me your gmail account or telegram ID or Skype ID to say the exact definition of the problem to you?

best regards.
S.S

Comment: Yes sure. My email id:
vishal.zinjade.java@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Knuth Morris Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm or the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm.  Without more details, it is hard to tell what exactly you are asking for, but these are known to be *very* fast search algorithms.  For Knuth Morris Pratt:

> Generally the algorithm gets faster as the pattern being searched for becomes longer.

I know that Stack Exchange typically prefers answers which have answers rather than links, but the algorithms are complex enough that they are better served by links.  The key to their performance is that they recognize that any failed match gives a great deal of additional information about other matches that must also fail.  This lets them operate in supra-linear time: they can actually do the search in O(n) time without actually comparing every character in the string.  It does so by realizing that, when a match fails, there's more information available than just "that one match failed."  It also says a lot about nearby matches that could or could not occur.  That lets them skip testing characters they can prove can never be part of the match.